# how to add a shell context menu for recycle bin by sharpshell?

Tags: c#, contextmenu, sharpshell

How to add a shell context menu for recycle bin by sharpshell?

Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Have you actually read the article on codeproject about this?

Comment: @t0mm13b  Of course, but I did not see anything about recycle bin context menu!

Answer (score 1):

The class GUID of the virtual Recycle Bin Folder in Windows systems is `{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}`.

You can specify a context menu handler to be registered for this class in SharpShell via the the COMServerAssociation attribute and specifying AssociationType = Class and specifying the class directly the following way:

```
[COMServerAssociation(AssociationType.Class, "{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}")]
public class MyContextMenuExtension: SharpContextMenu
{
  // ...
}
```